# How to stop Google search from linking to https?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, heroku, dns, search-engine

When I find my website through Google search results, it's using:

```
https://www.example.com
```

Since I don't yet have a valid SSL certificate, a warning appears in the browser --

```
"Your connection is not private"
```

I would like Google to link to my website using `http://example.com` rather than `https`. My other non-SSL web apps don't have this issue.

What steps can I take to fix this?

Comment: How do you imagine something like that would work? Google is conducting the search and providing the link with https protocol. There's nothing you can do on your end to prevent Google from doing that. Google's really been pushing https for the last two or three years, so I wouldn't count on things changing.

Comment: I figured this may be some configuration issue on my end. Why else would my other sites, which don't have SSL certificates, not receive this warning?@MarsAtomic

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's a Chrome specific issue. Did you try other browsers? That message should be occurring if you have a bad cert, not no cert. Anyhow, I don't think it has anything to do with your app, and it certainly has nothing to do with programming, so you've moved beyond the pale here.

Answer (score 1):

Double check you aren't forcing the use of SSL in settings

```
#config/environments/production.rb
# If this is set to true, change it to false
config.force_ssl = false
```

Also make sure you aren't linking to any external resources with an https:// connection, but use the protocol neutral // instead.  See the stylesheet_link_tag line and commented stack overflow question from this snippet in an application of mine that uses DataTables

```
# views/layouts/application.html.haml
-# Include DataTables stylesheets
-# http://datatables.net
-# BUGFIX
-# Note the lack of a http: protocol definition to prevent force_ssl config setting
-# from preventing content loading
-# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18121258/the-page-at-url-ran-insecure-content-from-url-in-chrome
= stylesheet_link_tag '//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css'
= javascript_include_tag '//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js'
```